# Angular - 2 way data binding multiple values

Tags: angular

Forgive the title, I am not entirely sure of what I am trying to ask here.

I have an html table and using `*ngFor` to iterate over a data object. Within this iteration, I print out the value of a specific field and attached an `*ngIf` to it. When my table is in "Edit Mode" that text value goes away and a dropdown menu is expose to allow the user to change the value.

The dropdown uses `ngModel` and I can see my data being updated correctly within my `json` that I have right below my dropdown. My issue however is that this dropdown is bound to the `OperatorID` in my object (which is correct) but the `Text` in the dropdown is a different part of the object.

**HTML:**

```
<td class="small col-md-1 oper">
  <span *ngIf="!inEditMode(r.RuleParentID, a.AttributeID)">
   <strong>{{ a.OperatorName }}</strong>
  </span>
  <select class="form-control input-sm" [(ngModel)]="a.OperatorID" *ngIf="inEditMode(r.RuleParentID, a.AttributeID)">
    <option *ngFor="let o of fetchOperatorList(a.AttributeID)" [value]="o.OperatorID" [selected]="o.OperatorID === a.OperatorID">{{ o.OperatorName }}</option>
  </select>
</td>
```

**Data Object:**

```
{
    "AttributeID": "2",
    "AttributeName": "Role",
    "OperatorID": "3",
    "OperatorName": "In List",
    "SqlOperator": "IN"
}
```

The issue I am facing is that once I change the value in the dropdown and it updates the `OperatorID` in my object, I then disable "Edit Mode" which turns the dropdown back into the interpolated text it printed from the `*ngFor`, which is `OperatorName` in the object.

This results in the name **not** getting updated and the value **is** getting updated.

Is there a way to bind on multiple values? When I select an option in my select for example, I want the select `value` to update `OperatorID` and the select `text` to update the `OperatorName`.

How should I approach this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If i understood your problem correctly, You need to update the `a.OperatorName` to whatever it corresponds to the new selection (Based on the id). You should be able to achieve this by binding to the select change event.

```
<select class="form-control input-sm"
        [(ngModel)]="a.OperatorID"
        *ngIf="inEditMode(r.RuleParentID, a.AttributeID)"
        (change)="onChange($event.target.value)">
    <option *ngFor="let o of fetchOperatorList(a.AttributeID)" [value]="o.OperatorID" [selected]="o.OperatorID === a.OperatorID">{{ o.OperatorName }}</option>
</select>
```

Then in your component.

```
public onChange(operatorId) {
    // update operator object in collection based on id 
}
```

Comment: Makes sense - in this case, its pointless even using `ngModel` then when I could just pass `$event` to the `onChange` and make both updates at the same time right?

Comment: yes, if you are to update the object in the collection then you don't need to bind the `ngModel`, as you'll replace the whole instance. you could  also probably do the change on the fly like this `(change)="a.OperatorName = $event.target.value` but Its bad as you'll end up with dodgy data if you don't update the whole thing

Comment: Sounds good - I will use the `onChange` event and then search my object for where I need to update the data and do so.

Comment: To write the better code you can change the (change) -> (ngModelChange) since you're using ngModel and [value] -> [ngValue]. Isn't it?

Comment: Beat me to the punch! Nice answer!

Comment: Probably! although if you need to replace the whole model, as for what I understand its selected by Id, you would need to update the collection. But this is a good observation,I did not know about this event, will definitely use in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using ngModel, you can use a function in the component and bind it to the change event of the select.

Template:

```
        <div>{{selectedOperator | json}}</div>
        <select class="form-control input-sm" #mySelect     
          (change)="onSelectChange(mySelect.value)">
          <option *ngFor="let o of operators" 
          [value]="o.OperatorID" [selected]="o.OperatorID ===     selectedOperator.OperatorID">{{ o.OperatorName }}</option>
        </select>
```

Component:

```
  selectedOperator;

    operators = [
      {
        OperatorID: 1,
        OperatorName: "Foo"
      },
      {
        OperatorID: 2,
        OperatorName: "Bar"
      },
      {
        OperatorID: 3,
        OperatorName: "Awesomesauce"
      }
    ]

    onSelectChange(id) {

      this.selectedOperator = this.operators.find(i => i.OperatorID === Number(id));


    }

    ngOnInit(){
      this.selectedOperator = this.operators[2];
  }
```

Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/G0N7xvVDJEokDEwnMsvS